# How can I rewrite part of an emailed url?

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm trying rewrite part of the url. We have an application that sends a link for a task and it uses the hostname of the machine in the URL. I want to rewrite this part of the URL to match the friendly name of the certificate for the site. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. An example of the emailed link is:

```
https://hostname.corp.domain.com/DP/DesktopDefault.aspx?source=mail&EP=kMOlYgO4KFpOsfDcXwOKhUE0GdmTkXp9QugT5e9c4%2byYm665yG
```

I cant figure out why it won't change from "hostname" to "app". Here is what I have so far, any help is much appreciated.

```
  <rule name="Task" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url="^([a-z].+.)corp.domain.com/dp/([a-z].+)$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="HOSTNAME" />
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="app" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="app.corp.domain.com/dp/{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^hostname.corp.domain.com$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://app.corp.domain.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```